# What is the significance of !== -1?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently a student learning Javascript and the following code came up in my work:

```
var currentInventory = [
  {
    name: 'Brunello Cucinelli',
    shoes: [
      {name: 'tasselled black low-top lace-up', price: 1000},
      {name: 'tasselled green low-top lace-up', price: 1100},
      {name: 'plain beige suede moccasin', price: 950},
      {name: 'plain olive suede moccasin', price: 1050}
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Gucci',
    shoes: [
      {name: 'red leather laced sneakers', price: 800},
      {name: 'black leather laced sneakers', price: 900}
    ]
  }
];

function filterBlackShoes(shoeList) {
  return shoeList.filter(function(shoe){
    return shoe.name.indexOf('black') !== -1;
  })
}

function renderBlackShoesForDesigner(designer, shoeList) {
  shoeList = filterBlackShoes(shoeList);
    return shoeList.map(function(shoe){
        return [designer, shoe.name, shoe.price].join(', ')
    })
}

function renderFilteredGoodsStringForDesigner(designerObject) {
  return renderBlackShoesForDesigner(designerObject.name, 
designerObject.shoes).join('\n');
}

function renderInventory(inventory) {
  return inventory.map(function(designerObject) {
    return renderFilteredGoodsStringForDesigner(designerObject);
  }).join('\n');
}
```

So I understand what the code does, it filters for the black shoes and returns that information.  I understand all of the aspects of how the code works except for what the !== -1 does.  I would go to my teachers but they are currently offline.  Can someone explain the significance of that to me?

Comment: Thats a comparison statement

Comment: I know that, but what is the significance of comparing it to -1

Comment: It's testing that the value is not `-1` according to the [*strict equality comparison algorithm*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-strict-equality-comparison) (i.e. it must be a number value of -1). The [*indexOf* method](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-string.prototype.indexof) returns -1 if no match is found.

Answer (score 3):

`indexOf` returns `-1` when the item can't be found. `!==` is a strict not equals operator. So the statement there is trying to say that the item is found.

Answer (score 1):

`indexOf` returns -1 when the substring doesn't exist in the string.  So `return shoe.name.indexOf('black') !== -1` will return true if "black" is in the string, and false if it isn't.

Comment: @RobG Bah, a string is just an array of characters ;)

Answer (score 0):

That is actually a comparison statement. You can see it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)

So, the statement `shoe.name.indexOf('black') !== -1` would return a `true` or `false` value depending upon how the content of `shoe.name`. So if there are no contents. It returns -1

Answer (score 0):

**indexOf()**

The indexOf() method returns the index within the calling String object of the first occurrence of the specified value, starting the search at fromIndex. Returns -1 if the value is not found.

You can see more example at MDN, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Not to get confused with [Array indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Answer (score 0):

From the Docs:

> The indexOf() method returns the position of the first occurrence of a specified value in a string.
>
> This method returns -1 if the value to search for never occurs.

Docs - [IndexOf()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)

In your `filterBlackShoes` function, you are filtering out the black shoes.

`name.indexOf('black') !== -1;` is saying if the `indexOf()` returns a number that is not -1, then an occurrence of the word 'black' has been found. If it returned -1, that would mean it couldn't find the world *black*.

To filter the black shoes, you are looking for an occurrence of the word *black* in the `name` attribute, and therefore a number that is not -1 signifies that an occurrence as been found.